# Run arbitrary code as function argument (similar to lambda)

Tags: python, lambda

I want to run arbitrary "code" in an argument like an anonymous function in Python.
How to do this in one single line?
Lambdas seems that does not work since they only take one expression.

```
def call_func(callback):
    callback()

def f():
    pkg_set_status(package_name, status)
    print('ok')

call_func(f)
```

Update:
Adding some context since the question is not entirely clear in my opinion.

I would like to run something like a multiline lambda or anonymous function.
Something like:

```
call_func(lambda:
   # my multiline code here
   pkg_set_status(package_name, status)
   print('ok')
)
```

so that the argument itself is the anonymous function body...

Update2: found the answer here
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99243/why-doesnt-python-allow-multi-line-lambdas
Looks like python does not support multiline lambdas by design.

Comment: `self.call_func(f())`

Answer (score 0):

it is simple really - the function, just use () after the parameter name.

Remember that in Python function are just like any other Python objects - you can pass them round.

```
def func():
    """Silly test function"""
    print('Running func')
    return 42

def call_something(callable):
    """Call something if we can"""
    # Sanity check before calling - not neccessary if you trust the caller
    if callable(callable):
       return callable()

# Use call_something to call func
call_something(func)
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve, call_func is obvious to call callable().

Comment: It issn't clear then what you were trying to acheive. From the comment you later added to the question it seems like you want a multi-line lambda - that isn't possible in Python, and it isn't planned to be added. Python isn't Javascript. 
To be honest though - if something is complex enough to need to need multiple lines it is complex enough to need a name: well that is my view.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? You can do your lambdas for each expression and pass them in as separate args to your super function:

```
def call_everything(*funcs):
    for func in funcs:
        func()


call_everything(lambda: print('ok'), lambda: print('hi!'))
```

Comment: Yes, that is kind of what I am trying to achieve, but the code looks like shit to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator syntax to pass in a callback as a `def` instead of a `lambda`.

```py
def call_func(callback):
    callback()

@call_func
def f():
    pkg_set_status(package_name, status)
    print('ok')
```

It's also possible to pass in other arguments. Here we're calling `reduce` with `range(10)` and the callback is `def`'ed below instead of passed in as a lambda. This style ends up looking similar to blocks in Ruby.

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> @lambda f: reduce(f, range(10))
... def f(a, b):
...   print(a, b)
...   return a+b
...
0 1
1 2
3 3
6 4
10 5
15 6
21 7
28 8
36 9
>>> f  # set to the return value of the reduce()
45
```

But you don't actually need a `def` here:

```py
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: print(a, b) or a+b, range(10))
0 1
1 2
3 3
6 4
10 5
15 6
21 7
28 8
36 9
45
```

Your example doesn't either:

```py
call_func(lambda:[
   pkg_set_status(package_name, status),
   print('ok'),
   ]
)
```

Python's lambdas are pretty much powerful enough to do anything a `def` can, despite being restricted to a single returned expression, because Python guarantees evaluation order of subexpressions. Many programming languages don't have statements at all, only expressions. Python's expression language alone is a complete programming language in its own right, but Python does look different when it's written without statements.